# Show AlertView when tapping tab in TabBar

Tags: ios, uialertview, uitabbar

**What I need**

I'd like to show an `UIAlertView` "Loading..." when I tap on a tab in my tabBar.

**Reason why I want to do that**

This is because that particular tab contains a `UIWebView` and is very slow, so when I tap on that tab it seems like my app is doing absolutely nothing for a few seconds. It is very ugly, so I'd like to show something to make the user know that the app is actually working.

**Questions**

In which position do I have to put it? If I write it in the ViewDidLoad, the AlertView is shown after those orrible few seconds. Is AlertView the best choice?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

add [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to your UIWebView viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
      [hud hide:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just supplying that link doesn't really solve anything. Link only answers with no summary or example code should be comments not answers and this should be a comment

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlerView` is not a good idea.

```
//Delegate method of UIWebView
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    }
}

//Delegate method of UIWebView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView_ 
{
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use this `UIActivityIndicatorView` when they could just set the `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` to be visible. Also this could would not do anything except throw a load of errors for not knowing what `yourActivityIndicator` is. Also where would you add it to the `UIWebView`? Missing so much from this answer -1

Comment: But webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad are called several times during the loading of the web page (yes, I think it's a stupid thing, too ._.). I don't think that's the right place where to put them..

Comment: You could easily set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];` in `webViewDidStartLoad:` and set it to `NO` in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` which would show the user that something is loading. Also you shouldn't give half an answer you should include all code that is the reason for my -1 because you haven't provide full code, otherwise I would have said it would have been an idea.

Comment: @Popeye I have edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep that in mind from next time...

Comment: OK I have removed my -1 but I have one minor suggestion. Wrap them in an `if statement` like `if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible])`

Comment: @Popeye I have added your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Sorry in `webViewDidStartLoad:` it should be `if(![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible])`

Answer (score 0):

Set your `tabBar` as a `delegate` on `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Setting tabBarController as a delegate
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
}
```

On your interface at  `.h` method add delegate `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

Implement this function and add your loading view, for each time that you press tabBar. The method below gets executed always when the user taps an item on tabbar.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        //Show loading form here
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            // Do something...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            });
        });
    }
```

P.S You need to add this method and set to delegate to every viewController which you need to show the alert view (Loading View)

For a loading view you can also load use MBProgressHUD as KingBabar pointed out. It has great features.

Comment: Not sure what this is meant to be but it certainly does answer the question -1

Comment: It does answer the question and -1? @Popeye look the idea of him was that he wants to show a loading view when user taps the TabBar, that what this delegate is responsible for, when user taps it, it tells the item that is tapped. And here he can implement the loading bar since the webView is very slow.

Comment: Finish your answer then because as it stands this doesn't answer anything.

Comment: How does this not stand for everything, I don't have his code here to provide an exact solution for this thing. You said you have no idea what this code stands for, so read about it, and explain to me why it's wrong, I am using it and it's working great. Also I answered to his questions. -1 without explanation nor point out why for my opinion is just wrong.

Comment: So if this works and some sort of alertView pops up where is your alertView code? I will state again this does nothing.

Comment: How do I set tabBar as a delegate, and where?
And where do I have to implement that function? In all the viewcontrollers I have in my tabBar?

Comment: Ales as I see you are dealing with tabBarController instead of tabBar, but anyway I have updated the answer.
@Popeye this is weird really, he knows how to show an alertView but he's asking for better ones, and there are plenty of them as KingBabar pointed out. Check out now how to show alertView.

Comment: Unfortunately this AlertView is like the others: it's shown after a few moments while the app looks immobile.

Comment: I added that line just to tell @Popeye because he said the code is not usefull just because of that, but I am updating the answer with code that MBPROGRESHUD has provided!

Comment: Why didn't you do that in the first place? What a load of trouble to get you to do what you should have done in the first place, given answers should be given in full not just half an answer and you expect the user to know the rest and this is why my -1 remains because you couldn't be bothered to give a full and complete answer. Just saying stick some code in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController` is a poor answer that has zero effort put into it.

Comment: @Popeye thats why I have updated it step by step, this has nothing to do with you, but as I understand you see this forum like we are at war or smth. If you don't approve my question, at least tell me where the error is and I'll fix it. Right now I have fixed it, and what, you keep your ego to still leave the vote down. If he needed more code, I'll just give him the best of my experience (I am not an expert), but there's no point in arguing here more about votes up and down.

Comment: What you have now provided is exactly what I was after some sort of effort being put into your answer instead of a poor answer unexplained answer. The reason I am leaving the -1 is because of the effort it took for you to actually update your answer with something that actually answers the question.

Comment: +1 for 3r1d, but I don't understand what should I do where you wrote: "Do something".
Those lines are to show the HUD asynchronously, right?

Comment: The whole idea of stackoverflow is for others is if others are struggling with an issue they can come here have look to see if any of the questions already asked are like theirs and if any of the answers help, so just putting stick some code in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` that will solve your issue is not a good answer at all, it requires explaining and shown how. If they already knew how to do it they wouldn't be asking and clearly the OP didn't understand since they are still asking questions regarding your code.

Comment: Maybe it's me: I'm new to iOS language.
Anyway, peace bros :D

Comment: Where is says //do something, you can add your code, and with the function of hideHUD you can hide the HUD by being loaded. @Popeye if you have a better idea you are welcome to write it down. But talking about performance, you should learn first how to do it, after you need to test it, and try new methods. It's no competition for me to argue with you, in the last comment you are right, but I am new to iOS too, so I have just experienced this way, you can share your own way. It's the first time someone is arguing with me, about my time or my effort to my answer cuz I am also working right now!